# Disable app name or package name to be detected

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm working on an application in which I want to restrict other apps to get my app or package name. Is it possible to do it? As of now, I didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: What does "get my app or package name" mean?

Comment: first of all: why would u wanna do this?
second: i am unaware of such a feature, as it would include somehow making folders invisible, which isn't something reasonable

Comment: Android 11 has new privacy policy and permission for requesting "all apps" from package manager (so your app would only be visible by launchers etc.). Unfortunately older versions provide unrestricted access to querying apps installed on the device.

Comment: @TK36 most of the time other parties can check which app is installed on device, which I don't want except my app should be visible from App Manager only.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to hide your package name or app in general, otherwise viruses would be hard to find and uninstall.

App name can kind of be hidden, but not from App Managers. What you can do is give a different name to the Launchable activity.

So your App can be called "My App - Best App Ever" in the PlayStore (Name is unrelated to the others), then your app name is "My App Name" declared in Manifest and then the launchable activity can be called "Launchable"

Users will see the second one (real app name) when uninstalling/managing your app through app managers and the Launchable name will be visible in Launchers and some other cases.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It may solve the issue for hidding the name but package name will still be available. And if anyone check which apps are installed, then he will be able to get my app...